# Finding intervals in pandas dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames. One dataframe (A) looks like:

```
Name.   gender     start_coordinate    end_coordinate    ID      
Peter     M             30                  150           1      
Hugo      M            4500                6000           2      
Jennie    F             300                 700           3
```

The other dataframe (B) looks like

```
ID_sim.  position      string      
  1         89            aa      
  4         568            bb     
  5        938437         cc
```

I want to accomplish two tasks here:

1. I want to get a list of indices for rows (from dataframe B) for which **position** column falls in the interval (specified by **start_coordinate** and **end_coordinate** column) in dataframe A.
   The result for this task will be:

```
lst = [0,1]. ### because row 0 of B falls in interval of row 1 in A and row 1 of B falls in interval of row 3 of A.
```

2. The indices that I get from task **1**, I want to keep it from dataframe B to create a new dataframe. Thus, the new dataframe will look like:

```
position     string          
89             aa 
568            bb
```

I used .between() to accomplish this task. The code is as follows:

```
lst=dfB[dfB['position'].between(dfA.loc[0,'start_coordinate'],dfA.loc[len(dfA)-1,'end_coordinate'])].index.tolist()
result=dfB[dfB.index.isin(lst)]
result.shape
```

However, when I run this piece of code I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

What could possibly be raising this error? And how can I solve this?

Comment: Do you match the dataframes on ID and ID_sim?

Comment: No I don't want to match on those because they can be different in two data frames. I want find intervals instead.

Comment: So you check if the postion on row 1 in dfB is higher than start_coordinate in dfA on row 1 and lower than end_coordinate in dfA on row 1?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want to do.

Comment: This is why I used .between but then I get an error.

Comment: @John if I am understanding correctly you want check position in dfB to see if it's contained in any interval in dfA?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try **numpy broadcasting** here

```
s, e = dfA[['start_coordinate', 'end_coordinate']].to_numpy().T
p = dfB['position'].to_numpy()[:, None]

dfB[((p >= s) & (p <= e)).any(1)]
```

---

```
   ID_sim.  position string
0        1        89     aa
1        4       568     bb
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Pandas IntervalIndex to get the positions, and afterwards, use a boolean to pull the relevant rows from `B` :

Create IntervalIndex:

```
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([*zip(A['start_coordinate'], 
                                               A['end_coordinate'])
                                          ], 
                                          closed='both')
```

Get indexers for `B.position`, create a boolean array with the values and filter `B`:

```
# get_indexer returns -1 if an index is not found.
B.loc[intervals.get_indexer(B.position) >= 0] 
Out[140]: 
   ID_sim.  position string
0        1        89     aa
1        4       568     bb
```

Comment: Thanks :) ... I didn't know about IntervalIndex.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Less elegant but easier to comprehend.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Name.','gender', 'start_coordinate','end_coordinate','ID'],
['Peter','M',30,150,1],
['Hugo','M',4500,6000,2],
['Jennie','F',300,700,3]]

data2 = [['ID_sim.','position','string'],
['1',89,'aa'],
['4',568,'bb'],
['5',938437,'cc']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2[1:], columns=data2[0])
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print (merged[(merged['position'] > merged['start_coordinate']) & (merged['position'] < merged['end_coordinate'])])
```